# Unable to set icon on electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Electron-builder version: 20.11.1
Electron-builder targets: win nsis

When I run yarn dist it throws the error Unable to set icon . Googling around I have discovered it is caused by a bug in rcedit and it was reported in november 2017, so it seems strange to me that no one has find a solutions until now. Are there any other solutions? My final goal is creating an installer for my application

Comment: Hi, could you add the simplest electron-builder.yml/setup that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: Here it is: https://hastebin.com/onixadiyur.json